# Which type of variable is more correct to specify - an abstract class or an interface?

Tags: php, oop

I have the following code:

```php
interface ModelInterface {}

abstract class AbstractModel {} 

// and there are many specific models that implement 
// the interface `ModelInterface` and inherit from the abstract class `AbstractModel`
```

Which type is correct to use in the `????` declaration? `AbstractModel` or `ModelInterface`?

```php
/** @var ???? $model */
$model = new $modelName();
$model->foo();

function baz(???? $model) {}

function bar(): ???? {}
```

If I use the `AbstractModel` type, this is a dependency inversion violation.

If I use `ModelInterface`, then the PhpStorm editor does not show me the available methods in `AbstractModel`, but only the methods that I declared in `ModelInterface`

Answer (score 1):

Generally it would depend on what you need.

There is no black and white correct/incorrect way to do this (although one could argue that there is something smelly on that design altogether).

It is (or should be) simple: what do you **need** to work? Does the code work with a `ModelInterface` or with an `AbstractModel`?

> If I use the AbstractModel type, this is a dependency inversion violation.

The problem here would not the type annotation or declaration, but the design. If your code really depends on `AbstractModel`, trying to hide it won't fix your issue. If it's right or wrong to depend on this abstract class... well, it would depend very much on how your code is structured and specific circumstances.

---

And if you absolutely need both, and you are on PHP 8.1+, you can always use [intersection types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-system.php#language.types.type-system.composite.intersection), to specify that the variable/argument/return *intersects* with both types:

```
/** @var AbstractModel&ModelInterface $model */
$model = new $modelName();
$model->foo();

function baz(AbstractModel&ModelInterface $model) {}

function bar(): AbstractModel&ModelInterface
```

As annotation, it would work even before PHP 8.1.